# Are the "out" and "in" instructions privileged instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

Are the `out` and `in` instructions privileged instructions? I assume they are because if they were not, then any process running in user mode can access port mapped I/O hardware. But I can't find anything online that confirms that.

Comment: yes they are or can be.  What did you find when you read the documentation?

Comment: which is oneline...

Answer (score 3):

They are tied to the I/O privilege level (IOPL), as documented here for [`OUT`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) and here for [`IN`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_139.html).  The IOPL is bits 12-13 of the `(R|E)FLAGS` register. If the current privilege level is greater than (i.e. has *less* privilege than) the value in the IOPL, `IN` and `OUT` will not work.

This obviously applies to operating modes other than real mode, which doesn't have any concept of privilege levels.

Comment: Note that there is also a privilege bitmap for the first 256 ports.

Comment: @fuz Yes, but this question was specifically about the instructions.

Comment: Right, but the point is that an operating system can configure things so that `outb 0x60` is allowed in a user-space process, but `outb 0x50` faults, right?  OTOH, Linux uses a larger bitmap in software, presumably catching the exception from `in`/`out` and checking (in software) if it should have been allowed.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioperm.2.html